# SQL count query within query

Tags: sql, group-by

I have two tables that I'm working with One dependent on the other. And I would like to get the information of the independent tables and count the number of times each row of data was used by the dependent table. With My current query I only get a record count of 1 when I know there in fact 38 records total. What am I doing wrong?

```
SELECT r.rid, r.name, COUNT(b.bid) AS brewtot 
FROM recipes r, brews b
WHERE r.uid = '#cookie.id#' AND b.rid = r.rid
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect what you want to do is add a

`GROUP BY b.rid`

assuming your question is "How many brews are there for each recipe."

Also you might want to use a `LEFT JOIN` to also count 0 rows when there is no brew to a recipe:

```
SELECT r.rid, r.name, COUNT(b.bid) AS brewtot 
FROM recipes r LEFT JOIN brews b
ON b.rid = r.rid
WHERE r.uid = '#cookie.id#'
GROUP BY b.rid
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select r.rid, r.name, count(b.bid) as brewtot
from recipes r inner join brews b on r.rid = b.rid 
where r.uid = '#cookie.id#' group by r.rid, r.name
```

That should work

Answer (score 0):

Add 'GROUP BY r.rid' at the end of your query.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do group by on rid.

```
SELECT r.rid, r.name, COUNT(b.bid) AS brewtot 
FROM recipes r, brews b
WHERE r.uid = '#cookie.id#' AND b.rid = r.rid 
group by r.rid
```

Do you want to also see all brews record too?.

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised the query even works without a group by?  Try:

```
SELECT  r.rid
,       r.name
,       COUNT(b.bid) AS brewtot 
FROM    recipes r
JOIN    brews b
ON      b.rid = r.rid
WHERE   r.uid = '#cookie.id#'
GROUP BY
        r.rid
,       r.name
```

On SQL Server with my test setup, this returns the correct count.